# Can a modulo function be linearized or alternatively expressed?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, linear-cryptanalysis

In order to try to simplify or alternatively express cryptographic functions I wonder if the modulo function can be alternatively expressed. Could for example a [Fourier series of a sawtooth wave](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html) or its discretization be useful? What would that look like for a given range and precision?

Comment: When the modulus is a power of two, $x\bmod n$ reduces to $x\&(n-1)$, where $\&$ is [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). That generalizes to $n$ of the form $b^k$, by expressing $x$ in base $b$ and keeping the $k$ low-order digits. That applies to any $n$ by expressing $x$ in base $n$, but is not much useful.

Comment: do you mean the function $x \mapsto x \pmod n,$ for some $n$? If yes, the above comment answers it.

Comment: how you approximate it also depends on the application, there is a paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/572.pdf that approximates the mod function based on sine series but it needs to use complex number arithmetic